# Creating polar-stereographic projection of HDF data subset?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, hdf

I have an HDF4 file.  I would like to create a geotif file containing a polar-stereographic projection of one of the HDF4 data sets.  I've tried using gdalwarp.  This works for some projection types, but it seems to need additional information (s_srs?):

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -t_srs '+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=90.0 +lon_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m' 'HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD10CM.A2017244.006.2017275033743.hdf":MOD_CMG_Snow_5km:Snow_Spatial_QA' MOD10CM.gdal.psg.lat_true_90.tif

Creating output file that is 5692P x 5692L.
Processing HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD10CM.A2017244.006.2017275033743.hdf":MOD_CMG_Snow_5km:Snow_Spatial_QA [1/1] : 0Using internal nodata values (e.g. 255) for image HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD10CM.A2017244.006.2017275033743.hdf":MOD_CMG_Snow_5km:Snow_Spatial_QA.
Copying nodata values from source HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD10CM.A2017244.006.2017275033743.hdf":MOD_CMG_Snow_5km:Snow_Spatial_QA to destination MOD10CM.gdal.psg.lat_true_90.tif.
ERROR 1: Too many points (441 out of 441) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 0,0,5692,5692, skipping.
...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

The file that is produced is empty.